# how do I read from a database for a specific row in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

so I am trying to make a very simple database, I am using sqlite3 and I am ever so new to programming with python and other things. My goal is to be able to input a name which is a section in my table and have it display the row that that name is found in. I have found tutorials where they just do normal data as opposed to dynamic searches.  I don't have much of an example to show, but here 
is where I'm working from

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE nameinfo(name TEXT, age REAL, color TEXT)")

def enter_dynamic_data():
    name = input("What\s their name? ")
    age = float(input("How old are they? "))
    color = input("What\'s their favorite color? ")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO nameinfo(name, age, color) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (name, age, color))

conn.commit()

def read_from_database():
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM nameinfo")
    for row in c.execute(sql): #It names off the names that I can select from
        print(row[0])
        inp = input("Who would you like to know more about? ")
    for row in c.execute(sql): #Where I plan to have it only show a specific 
row, being the name age and favorite color of a person

        print(row)


read_from_database()

conn.close()
```

Comment: I think this question has more to do with `SQL` itself as opposed to Python or SQLite. Do learn basics of SQL queries first and then it'll be much easier. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp  What I think you're asking is that you want to extract a certain data row for instance we do this `select name, age, color from table where name=='Matthew'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT * FROM nameinfo WHERE name = ?`. Complete code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE nameinfo(name TEXT, age REAL, color TEXT)")

def enter_dynamic_data(name, age, color):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO nameinfo(name, age, color) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (name, age, color))

create_table()
enter_dynamic_data("jack", 20, "green")
enter_dynamic_data("jill", 30, "red")
conn.commit()

def read_from_database():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM nameinfo"
    for row in c.execute(sql):  # It names off the names that I can select from
        print(row[0])
    name = "jack"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM nameinfo WHERE name = ?"
    for row in c.execute(sql, (name,)):
        print(row)

read_from_database()

conn.close()
```